# NoClassDefFoundError okhttp3 not compiled into dex

Tags: android, ant, okhttp, dex, android-multidex

When I try to use the `okhttp` class , it throws an exception.

I decompile my app, found that no `okhttp3` class is included.

My project is an Eclipse project target on 4.3 with `okhttp3.2` and it has methods over 64k problem. We use ant to compile the apk.

To fix the problem, we put some jars into a 2nd dex using this solution: [Dex65536](https://github.com/mmin18/Dex65536).

I have already tried to put `okhttp3` in the main dex or the 2nd dex, both are not compiled into the dex.

I added okio

I tried to build path

I update jdk to 1.8 and adt v23

I tried to use 4.4 sdk

> 274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221): Process: com.sanweidu.TddPay, PID: 25221
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.util.http.HttpUtil.(HttpUtil.java:65)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.util.http.HttpUtil.(HttpUtil.java:43)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.util.http.HttpUtil$HttpUtilHolder.(HttpUtil.java:53)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.util.http.HttpUtil.getInstance(HttpUtil.java:61)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.model.social.LiveInfoModel.requestLiveInfo(LiveInfoModel.java:18)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.presenter.social.LiveInfoPresenter.requestLiveInfo(LiveInfoPresenter.java:27)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at com.sanweidu.TddPay.activity.main.SixthFragment.onResume(SixthFragment.java:70)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1521)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   05-17 22:47:40.274: E/AndroidRuntime(25221):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)

Answer (score 0):

Look in the "Order and Export" tab and make sure the checkbox beside the library you want (okhttp3) is checked off to assure that it is incorporated into the binary.